# Why is std::nextafter not constant expression?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++23

Why code below has no problem with a2 but does not compile for z1?

```
#include <cmath>    // std::nextafter
#include <limits>   // std::numeric_limits

int main ()
{
    constexpr float a1 {1.f};
    constexpr float a2 {std::nextafter(a1, std::numeric_limits<float>::max())};
    constexpr float z0 {0.f};
    constexpr float z1 {std::nextafter(z0, std::numeric_limits<float>::max())};
    
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with GCC 13.2

```
In file included from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/cmath: In function 'int main()':
<source>:9:39:   in 'constexpr' expansion of 'std::nextafter(((float)z0), std::numeric_limits<float>::max())'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/cmath:2417:32: error: '__builtin_nextafterf(0.0f, 3.40282347e+38f)' is not a constant expression
 2417 |   { return __builtin_nextafterf(__x, __y); }
```

So GCC compiled a2 correctly but is unable to compile z1.

Note:
Clang 14.0 and MSVC 19.38 have problems even with a2.

Comment: I get errors for both `a2` and `z1`: https://godbolt.org/z/1cfs5q8TK

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/9aWMM8efs - no problem with a2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

libstdc++13.2.0 does not seem to implement [`std::nextafter()`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-13.2.0/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/tr1/cmath#L894-L910) as `constexpr` yet.

GCC turns `std::nextafter(a1, std::numeric_limits<float>::max())` into a constant value. This is a lucky exceptional case when compilers can evaluate rare expressions as constexpr even if they are not marked as such.

GCC can't turn `std::nextafter(z0, std::numeric_limits<float>::max())` into a constant value, it turns `__builtin_nextafterf()` into the call to the C function `nextafterf()` that can't be constexpr. See https://godbolt.org/z/v7KMrTdfW

The code can be simplified to

```
#include <cmath>    // std::nextafter
#include <limits>   // std::numeric_limits

int main ()
{
    constexpr float a2 {std::nextafter(1.f, std::numeric_limits<float>::max())};
    constexpr float z1 {std::nextafter(0.f, std::numeric_limits<float>::max())};
    return 0;
}
```

with the similar Assembler result: https://godbolt.org/z/KE9vGd6j7

Comment: An interesting thing to note is that it seems GCC only doesn't do the optimization when the first parameter is `0`.  Any other value I use gets the code the compile.

Comment: @NathanOliver It seems to me that it is true. As it cannot make constexpr function https://godbolt.org/z/v381ordPz but can optimize it away.

Comment: @273K a2 is not 1 (see godbolt in comment above) but it can optimize it away as iostream standard precision is 6. But your answer make a point.

Comment: @TomášNadrchal You are right, I read the Assembler improperly.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think the thing about not const-expressing `nextafter(0.)` is because the next value is a denormalized float, which could be rounded to zero at runtime. `nextafter(std::numeric_limits<float>::min(), …)` gets optimized away. `nextafter(std::numeric_limits<float>::denorm_min(), …)` does not

Comment: Compiling with `-fno-trapping-math -fno-math-errno` also gets rid of the `nextafter` calls. So I guess it's less about potentially rounding denormalized numbers to zero and more about those two features

Comment: "_This is a lucky exceptional case when compilers can evaluate rare expressions as constexpr even if they are not marked as such._": No, that would be non-conforming to the standard. The compiler is not allowed to accept the `constexpr` variable initialization if `std::nextafter` is not marked `constexpr`. GCC is (intentionally) non-conforming and considers the math functions to be `constexpr` even if they aren't. In C++23 the second case will fail because the result is subnormal and would raise FE_UNDERFLOW.

Answer (score 3):

Since C++23 most C library math functions, including `std::nextafter`, are marked `constexpr` and generally usable in constant expression. However, there is an exception to this if the call would set `errno` or would raise any floating point exception other than `FE_INEXACT` (according to the semantics of ISO C Annex F as applicable to the floating point types).

This guarantees that floating point exceptions and the global `errno` that were intended to be observable at runtime don't "vanish" (except for `FE_INEXACT` which was excluded).

So, if you are asking why `z1` doesn't compile in C++23 mode, then it is because given that `float` on GCC is an IEEE 754 type and the result would be subnormal, ISO C Annex F applies and specifies `std::nextafter` to raise `FE_UNDERFLOW`, making the call non-eligible for constant expression evaluation under the exceptions I mentioned above.

If you are asking why `a2` does compile with GCC even in C++20 or earlier mode, then it is because GCC even before C++23 handled the C standard library math functions as if they were marked `constexpr`, although that's technically not conforming to the standard.

According to the standard `a2`'s initialization *must* produce a diagnostic before C++23, because the initializer calls a function that isn't marked `constexpr` (and the compiler may not add it implicitly). Calling a non-`constexpr` function in an expression disqualifies that expression from being a constant expression.

If you are asking why Clang and MSVC don't accept either variable, then it is probably because they haven't implemented the C++23 changes yet.

Comment: **although that's technically not conforming to the standard.** How so? It was not required to be `constexpr` but it was not prohibited to be `constexpr`. Built-in functions are often implicit contsexpr.

Comment: @273K Yes it was prohibited. It is a well-known intentional divergence of GCC from the standard: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/constexpr.functions#1.sentence-2

Comment: You have quoted that the `constexpr` keyword shall not be used in any standard library function declaration except if `constexpr` is explicitly required. 1. `__builtin_nextafterf()` is not a standard library function. 2. Missing `constexpr` does not prohibit a function from being used in constant expression context.

Comment: @273K OP is using the standard library function `std::nextafter`, not a compiler built-in. And missing `constexpr` on a function being called disqualifies from being a constant expression (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5.2), which in turn, given that the variable being initialized is marked `constexpr` implies that the program must be ill-formed (with a diagnostic required) per https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.constexpr#10.sentence-3 (because of the word "_shall_").

Comment: I don't see there "disqualifies" or "then and only then". I consider the whole paragraph 5 as required but not limited.

Comment: @273K https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5 is a proper definition for the term "_core constant expression_". As a definition it doesn't leave room for anything else being one. And being a "_core constant expression_" is a necessary condition for being a "_constant expression_" which is defined later in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#11. The wording "A [italic term] is a [...]" clearly indicates that the sentence is supposed to be a definition of [italic term].

Comment: @273K This is different from C btw. which to some degree explicitly permits implementations to consider expressions to be constant expressions even if the standard doesn't mandate it. In C++ the language fully specifies whether or not an expression is a constant expression (some unresolved defects and implemenation-defined choices aside).

Comment: An entity is a *permitted result of a constant expression* if ..., or if it is a non-immediate function.

Comment: @273K That's the definition for the term "_permitted result of a constant expression_" which doesn't appear in anything relevant to my previous comments. It is only referenced in the definition of "_constant expression_" to further restrict it, but that definition already has the necessary condition "_A constant expression is either a glvalue core constant expression [...] or a prvalue core constant expression [...]_": As explained above, the full-expression of the initialization already fails being a _core constant expression_, so it doesn't matter what else the definition requires.

Answer (score 0):

`nextafter` was not required to be a `constexpr` function before C++23. Since that's still a new standard, many standard library implementations have not implemented it yet.

Comment: I would agree, but why a2 compile and z1 does not? I would expect either both to compile (implemented) or not compile (not implemented).

Comment: @TomášNadrchal It is non-conforming behavior that GCC also has in <C++23 modes. GCC is known for having added `constexpr` specifiers to math functions even though that wasn't permitted by the standard.

Comment: @NicolBolas There is an exception to use in constant expressions if a floating point exception would be raised, so `z1` will fail in C++23 as well, see my answer.